# Magento CE ADMIN- how to set a top level navigation to link to a category page with a layered navigation filter pre selected?

Tags: magento, url

I tried changing the url key in Admin > catalog > manage categories -- select the category > general > url key.

I changed the url key from

> all-products

to

> all-plants.html#stock_status=1&gan_data=true

However upon saving, Magento changed the url key to: all-plants-html-stock-status-1-gan-data-true

The goal here is to auto show only in-stock products for this category (I don't want to disable them)

I also tried using the Magento rewrite rule (admin > catalog > url rewrite management) to add a URL rewrite using the

> Request Path: all-plants.html#stock_status=1&gan_data=true

I get the following error: Anchor symbol (#) is not supported in request path

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change url path use .htaccess file link below

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F